# Compute $P_0$ for a $M/M/2$ queue

Tags: probability

> For a $M/M/2$ queue the balance equations start with:
>
> \begin{cases}
> \lambda P_0 = \mu P_1 & \\
> (\lambda + \mu) P_1 = \lambda P_1 + 2 \mu P_2 \\
> (\lambda + 2 \mu) P_n = \lambda P_{n-1} + 2 \mu P_{n+1} \\
> \end{cases}

Then they deduce from this (with $\rho = \lambda/\mu$) that:

$$ P_n = \frac{\rho^n}{2^{n-1}} P_0 $$

The boundary condition is

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n = 1 $$

Then conclude that

$$ P_0 = \frac{1 - \rho/2}{1 + \rho/2} $$

---

Could someone please show how they deduced $P_n$ from the balance equations, and also $P_0$ from the boundary condition?  I have tried applying a geometric series to the sum of $P_n$ but I am missing the $+$ sign on the bottom

$$ 2 P_0 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{\rho}{2} \right)^n = 1 $$

$$ \Rightarrow P_0 \frac{1}{1-\rho/2} = \frac{1}{2} $$

$$ \Rightarrow P_0 = \frac{1 - \rho/2}{2} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the question in the title for the general $M/M/s$, i.e. $s$ servers.

I think that will be more informative for you.

$$P_1 = \frac{a_0}{d_1}P_0$$

$$P_2 = \frac{a_0a_1}{d_1d_2}P_0$$

$$\vdots$$

$$P_n = \frac{a_0a_1 \cdots a_{n-1}}{d_1d_2 \cdots d_n}P_0$$

Where $P_0$ can be determined from

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n = \left(1 + \frac{a_0}{d_1} + \frac{a_0a_1}{d_1d_2} \cdots \right)P_0 = 1 \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:(1)$$

Here $a_n = \lambda$ and

$$ d_n =
\begin{cases}
n\mu,  & 0 < n < s \\
s\mu, & n \geq s
\end{cases}
$$

from this you can determine

$$ P_n =
\begin{cases}
[(s \rho)^n /n! ]P_0,  & n < s \\
\\
[(\rho^n s^s) /s! ]P_0, & n \geq s
\end{cases}
\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: (2)$$

where $\rho = \lambda/(s\mu)$

Now to answer your question. From equation $(1)$ and $(2)$ $P_0$ is obtained by equating

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n = P_0\left[\sum_{n=0}^{s-1}\frac{(s \rho)^n}{n!} + \sum_{n=s}^{\infty}\frac{\rho^n s^s}{s!}\right] = 1 \:\:\:\:\:\: (3)$$

Now we use the summation formula

$$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{x^k}{1-x} \:\:\:\:\ |x|<1$$

and rewrite equation $(3)$ as

$$P_0 = \left[\sum_{n=0}^{s-1}\frac{(s \rho)^n}{n!} + \frac{s^s}{s!}  \sum_{n=s}^{\infty}\rho^n \right]^{-1} = \left[\sum_{n=0}^{s-1}\frac{(s \rho)^n}{n!}+\frac{(s\rho)^s}{s!(1-\rho)}\right]^{-1}$$

provided $\rho = \lambda/(s\mu) < 1$

This is the general formula for $P_0$.

Comment: Is my book wrong then?  because when computing with this equation I don't get the same result, i.e. with $s=2$ $\displaystyle P_0 = \frac{1}{1/2+\rho+4\rho/(1-\rho)} \neq \frac{1-\rho/2}{1+\rho/2}$

Comment: @Sunhwa Yes, something is not right. I dont have time right now, but i will check it as soon as possible.

Comment: Oh gosh nevermind they are equal!  I was using $s$ in both factorials .. So $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+2\rho + 2\rho^2/(1-\rho)}$ does equal $\displaystyle \frac{1-\rho/2}{1+\rho/2}$  Thank you!